# express fetch promise will not resolve before render

Tags: express, async-await, fetch, pug

I have an express route and I want to send back the result of a fetch to my pug template. I know my fetch URL works as I have checked it with postman and the data comes back as it should. I would like to store the fetch of the result to the variable called `weather` at the bottom of the route. My template looks for this variable to exist before adding weather to the template

I have also logged my form data to make sure the form is sending the data to my express server

I get this error in my command console when logging the return:

```
Promise { <pending> }
(node:18060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

I think the issue must be with my promise structure or perhaps it has to do with CORS not being enabled in my app? I'm not getting any errors and I'm hoping someone might have an answer for me??

```
router.post("/", async(req, res, next)=>{
  console.log(req.body.selectedCity)
  console.log(req.body.selectedState)
  console.log(req.body.selectedZip)

    var result = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${req.body.selectedCity}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`)
      .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result.json())
    })
      .then((result)=>{
        console.log(result.json())
    res.render('index', {states:[
      {
        id:"none",
        name:"choose"
      },
      {
        id:"OH",
        name:"Ohio"
      },
      {
        id:"UT",
        name:"Utah"
      },
      {
        id:"VT",
        name:"Vermont"
      },

      {
        id:"VA",
        name:"Virginia"
      },
      {
        id:"WA",
        name:"Washington"
      },
      {
        id:"WV",
        name:"West Virginia"
      },
      {
        id:"WI",
        name:"Wisconsin"
      },
      {
        id:"WY",
        name:"Wyoming"
      }

    ],weather:result})
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an uncorrect syntax on async/await.

You do not use `.then` in async/await but you just `await` the promise and store the result in a variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
var result = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${req.body.selectedCity}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`)
      .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result.json())
    })
      .then((result)=>{
        console.log(result.json())
    res.render [...]
```

Becomes:

```
const result = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${req.body.selectedCity}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`);
console.log(result.json())
res.render [...]
```

Try and avoid `var` as it may lead to unexpected behavior.

Try using `axios` as a fetch library, it's much cleaner than fetch.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

This way it's just `const result = await axios.get([...]`

Answer (score 0):

This should be structured this way instead -

```
fetch('url')
     .then(result=>result.json)
     .then(result=>res.render())
```

You should also remove `async` keyword from the callback function provide to `router.post`.

Comment: Upon trying this I get the following error  ```javaScript json() { var _this2 = this; return consumeBody.call(this).then(function (buffer) { try { return JSON.parse(buffer.toString()); } catch (err) { return Body.Promise.reject(new FetchError(`invalid json response body at ${_this2.url} reason: ${err.message}`, 'invalid-json')); } }); }```   I'm not sure why the synax is invalid?